# Parsing a date format with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Using rubular http://rubular.com/ I'm trying to parse the hours minutes and seconds from a format `4H40M20S`

So far I have this

```
(\d*)H(\d*)M(\d*)S
```

Which works fine for `4H40M20S` but not for `40M20S`

What do I need to change to get it to work in this case?

Comment: Use optional groups: [`(?:(\d*)H)?(\d*)M(\d*)`](http://rubular.com/r/6t5ZsjtHaA). With `(?:...)?` you can make any part of the regex optional.

Comment: You're right Casimir I made a mistake, I've edited it to correct this mistake!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're after something like:

```
([\d]+[HMS])+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NhHG4SlWDHYGPVjF)

---

If you want to capture each section seperately, then use:

```
([\d]+H)?([\d]+M)?([\d]+S)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/uzeld1EdW4ZHEDqn)

Comment: And how do you extract hours, minutes, seconds values with this pattern?

Comment: only seconds are mandatory? why not minutes or hours? To make your pattern more robust (with all groups optional), you can use a lookbehind at the end of the pattern to check if one of your groups exists, something like: `(?<=[0-9][HMS])` or an other condition anywhere if you have a better idea. (you can check if groups exists after the match too)

Comment: Because the OP hasn't stated a format for mandatory group(s) - I've assumed that in order for a time to occur, there has to be at least seconds which is why I've made that group mandatory. You're absolutely right, the eventuality could be catered for (and if it were me, I probably would do) but it hasn't been asked for here.

Comment: How is `[\d]+` different than `\d+`?